# Non-binary tree c++

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, binary-tree

I would like to create a non-binary tree. I thought of a structure of this type with a pointer of pointer

```
struct tree{
    string name;
    int sonc;
    tree** son;
};
```

I crash for both large entries

```
void insertSon(tree* &a, string n){

if (a->sonc==0){
    a->son= new tree*;}

a->son[a->sonc]= new tree;
a->son[a->sonc]->name=n;
a->son[a->sonc]->sonc=0;
a->sonc++;}
```

but also in cancellation

```
void deleteTree(tree* &a){
for (int i=0;i<(a->sonc);++i){
    deleteTree(a->son[i]);
}
delete a;}
```

main cpp with tree population

```
tree *tree1;
tree1=new tree;


tree1->name="C:\\TEMP";
tree1->sonc=0;
insertSon(tree1,"C:\\TEMP\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfile1.txt");
insertSon(tree1,"C:\\TEMP\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfile2.txt");
insertSon(tree1,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1");

tree *lastf1=tree1->son[tree1->sonc-1];
insertSon(lastf1,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfile3.txt");
insertSon(lastf1,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfile4.txt");
insertSon(lastf1,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2");

tree *lastf2=lastf1->son[lastf1->sonc-1];
for (int i=0;i<100;++i){
insertSon(lastf2,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfile5.txt");
insertSon(lastf2,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfile6.txt");
insertSon(lastf2,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfile7.txt");
insertSon(lastf2,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfile8.txt");
insertSon(lastf2,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfile9.txt");
insertSon(lastf2,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfileA.txt");
insertSon(lastf2,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfileB.txt");
insertSon(lastf2,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfileC.txt");
insertSon(lastf2,"C:\\TEMP\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\aadvfdbdsbdfgfileD.txt");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Most likely the bug revolves around not correctly allocating an array for the tree pointers in `insertSon`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong in that this line:

```
a->son= new tree*;
```

allocates just a single pointer, but you are trying to use it as an array of pointers.

Rather than mess around with arrays, use vector. You could have

```
std::vector< tree * > son;
```

Of course you still need to take care of the pointers in the vector. You could use `shared_ptr<tree>` or `unique_ptr<tree>` if available for the children.

```
std::vector< shared_ptr< tree > > son;
```

or

```
std::vector< unique_ptr< tree > > son;
```

(with `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` either in `namespace std` or `namespace boost`)

Comment: It should almost definitely *not* be `shared_ptr`.

Comment: thank you, i solved with vector< tree* > son; and (a->son).push_back(atmp); on insertSon. what are the advantages of shared_ptr and unique_ptr?

Answer (score 1):

You never allocate an array at `son`, just a single `tree`.

You are duplicating the functionality of `std::vector` exactly.  Use `std::vector` instead of managing the array yourself.

Comment: +1 but unfortunately you *cannot* use `std::vector` here because it doesn’t support incomplete types (although it will in practice work with many compilers / library implementations). Yes, that’s a major design error in the library.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that.  Thanks for the info.  Here is a good article I found that explains the subject: http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-containers-of-inc/184403814

Comment: @japreiss Well, yes, that article is wrong. We’ve had a long discussion about it and there is no reason why other containers, such as `std::map`, couldn’t work with incomplete types. In fact, I’ve written a very simple prototype to prove that it’s possible.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all

works with these changes

```
struct tree{
    string name;
    int sonc;
    vector< tree* > son;
};
```

and the insertion procedure

```
void insertSon(tree* &a, string n){
tree *atmp;
atmp = new tree;
atmp->name=n;
atmp->sonc=0;
(a->son).push_back(atmp);
a->sonc++;}
```

what are the advantages of shared_ptr and unique_ptr?